# How to sort the Array that contains date in strings in descending order?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to sort the array that contains date string in descending order, I have tried SO answers, but I am getting wrong output.

Please see my code as below:

```
NSArray *dateArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"01/12/2012",@"01/26/2011",@"02/09/2005",@"02/24/2006",@"03/19/2007",@"07/14/2011",@"08/17/2007",@"10/04/2007",@"10/31/2006",@"12/05/2012",@"12/06/2006",@"12/23/2008",nil];
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY"];
NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<[dateArray count]; i++) {

    NSString *dt=[dateArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDate *newDt=[formatter dateFromString:dt];
    [tempArr addObject:newDt];
}
NSLog(@"tempArr is %@",tempArr);
```

I am getting Console output like as below:

> 2013-08-27 15:29:50.418 sample[3688:c07] tempArr is (
>       "2011-12-24 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2010-12-18 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2004-12-18 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2005-12-24 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2006-12-23 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2010-12-18 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2006-12-23 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2006-12-23 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2005-12-24 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2011-12-24 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2005-12-24 18:30:00 +0000",
>       "2007-12-22 18:30:00 +0000"
>   )

I don't know why "12" is coming in the place of Month and also the date format not coming like the format I specified.

Comment: The `MM/DD/YYYY` date format is wrong, use `MM/dd/yyyy`. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Comment: @rckoenes is right. Where are you sorting it anyway?

Comment: @rckoenes Ya i did this change, but still i am getting the same output.

Comment: See my answer. In your code you aren't actually sorting anything. If you want an array sorted in a certain order you have to actually sort it.

Comment: Read the spec for NSArray, perhaps?

Comment: And how is the above intended to sort anything?

Comment: And understand that an NSDate contains no timezone or format.  It always prints in the same format -- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z (or something like that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, first off, you're not actually sorting anything in your code...

You should do something like this...

```
// create the string array
NSArray *dateArray = @[@"01/12/2012", @"01/26/2011", @"02/09/2005", @"02/24/2006", @"03/19/2007", @"07/14/2011", @"08/17/2007", @"10/04/2007", @"10/31/2006", @"12/05/2012", @"12/06/2006", @"12/23/2008"];

// create the date formatter with the correct format
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// fast enumeration of the array
for (NSString *dateString in dateArray) {
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [tempArray addObject:date];
}

// sort the array of dates
[tempArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate *date1, NSDate *date2) {
    // return date2 compare date1 for descending. Or reverse the call for ascending.
    return [date2 compare:date1];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);
```

**EDIT TO PUT INTO STRING ARRAY**

```
NSMutableArray *correctOrderStringArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDate *date in tempArray) {
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [correctOrderStringArray addObject:dateString];
}

NSLog(@"%@", correctOrderStringArray);
```

Also, read up more about `NSDate`, `NSString` and `NSDateFormatter`. Especially how they interact with each other.

`NSDate` is a point in time. It does not (and never does) contain any formatting information.

`NSDateFormatter` doesn't hold any information about a specific date (i.e. point in time).  It is used to take a date and produce a string based on the `NSDate` and the `format` that you give it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: +1. Anyway you can make it slightly shorter with `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];`

Comment: Thanks. You can't use `compare:` for descending :) I edited. For descending you need to reverse the compare call. Or you could sort using `compare:` and then reverse the entire array.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the descending part. You're right.

Comment: I missed it to begin with too. But edited afterwards. Was going to change to use your method until I realised.

Comment: @Fogmeister I am gettin the output like this ""2012-12-04 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2012-01-11 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2011-07-13 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2011-01-25 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2008-12-22 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2007-10-03 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2007-08-16 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2007-03-18 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2006-12-05 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2006-10-30 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2006-02-23 18:30:00 +0000",
    "2005-02-08 18:30:00 +0000"" I need only month, date and year in the format MM/DD/YYYY .

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't want this thing "18:30:00 +0000" in each object. And the format is also not what i am expecting

Comment: NSDate does not equal the string format of a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]`

Instead of what you have in Line 3.
This should give you the date format you are expecting. With regards to sorting, I am a little confused. You have no code that sorts. Are you trying to sort or just format the date string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build yourself a suitable comparator:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSComparator myDateComparator = ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1,
                                                    id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    return [date2 compare:date1]; // sort in descending order
};
```

then simply sort the array by doing:

```
NSArray *dateArray = @[@"01/12/2012", @"01/26/2011", @"02/09/2005",
                       @"02/24/2006", @"03/19/2007", @"07/14/2011",
                       @"08/17/2007", @"10/04/2007", @"10/31/2006",
                       @"12/05/2012", @"12/06/2006", @"12/23/2008"];

NSArray *sortedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:myDateComparator];

NSLog(@"Sorted array is %@", sortedArray);
```

This sorts **the strings** (and not any modified array). You could also use string manipulation and convert m/d/y to y-m-d, but i guess for small data sets this approach would be fine.