# Find maximum and minimum date in array

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have a array like

```
    "11 Aug 2015",
    "24 Sep 2014",
    "25 Aug 2014",
    "07 Aug 2014",
    "07 Aug 2014"
```

i want to find maximum and minimum dates in it.

```
modifieddateArray.valueForKeyPath("@max.self")
modifieddateArray.valueForKeyPath("@min.self")
```

i used the above functions it gives the out like

> max as 25 Aug 2014
>
> min as 07 Aug 2014

but max date is 11 Aug 2015 and min as 07 Sept 2014

It considering on the first value greater as 25 and least as 07. How could i solve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to convert this string formatted date into an `NSDate` object and then run maximum/minimum date on it.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462763/how-to-sort-the-array-that-contains-date-in-strings-in-descending-order

Comment: Thanks dude got an idea.

Answer (score 7):

### By using Swift's Powerful Built-in functions:

```
// Operator Overloading Methods
func >(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}

// String to date
func dateFromString(dateStr: String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd LLL yyyy"

    // Eric D's suggestion, forcing locale to en_EN
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_EN")

    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)!
}

// Date to String
func stringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd LLL yyyy"

    // Eric D's suggestion, forcing locale to en_EN
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_EN")

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}

// Array of String Dates
var dates = ["11 Aug 2015",
    "24 Sep 2014",
    "25 Aug 2014",
    "07 Aug 2014",
    "07 Aug 2014"]

// Map the Strings to NSDate
var dateInstances = dates.map({dateFromString($0)})

// Find Max
let maxVal = stringFromDate(dateInstances.reduce(dateInstances[0]){$0 > $1 ? $1 : $0})

// Find Min
let minVal = stringFromDate(dateInstances.reduce(dateInstances[0]){$0 < $1 ? $1 : $0})
```

### Playground Output:

[image: Playground Output]

Comment: In "String to date", it will crash with other locales than English (because 'Aug' is only valid in English, for example). To prevent this, force the locale accordingly to the string one. In this case: `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_EN")`.

Comment: @EricD. Thanks for your suggestion, a really good point. I added it right away :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the most efficient way to do this, but pretty simple and had some fun coding this:

```
var dates = ["11 Aug 2015",
            "24 Sep 2014",
            "25 Aug 2014",
            "07 Aug 2014",
            "07 Aug 2014"]

        var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        var monthsNum = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]


        func convertToInt (date : String) -> Int {

            var arr = split(date) {$0 == " "}

            var c = 1
            for month in months {
                if (arr[1] == month) {
                    if (c < 10) {
                        return (arr[2]+"0"+String(c)+arr[0]).toInt()!
                    }
                    else {
                        return (arr[2]+String(c)+arr[0]).toInt()!
                    }

                }
                c++
            }

            return 0
        }

        func convertToString (date : Int) -> String {

            var dateString = String(date) as NSString

            var year = dateString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 4))
            var month = dateString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 4, length: 2))
            var day = dateString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 6, length: 2))

            var c = 0
            for curMonth in monthsNum {

                if (curMonth == month) {
                    return year+" "+months[c]+" "+day
                }
                c++
            }


            return ""

        }

        var newDates = [Int]()

        for date in dates {
            newDates.append(convertToInt(date))
        }


        println(convertToString(maxElement(newDates)))
        println(convertToString(minElement(newDates)))
```

Comment: This is not only "not the most efficient way" but prone to fail when dealing with `Locale` and taking advantage of Swift's powerful functions. Bad idea to hard code date values and names.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this

```
 var itemsArray ["24 Aug 2014","29 Jul 1990","06 Jan 2050","18 OCT 2014","24 Aug 2019"]


    for item in modifieddateArray {
        var maxDate2 : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(item as! String)! //as! NSDate
        var value : Int = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(maxDate2))
        itemsArray.addObject(value)
    }
    //println(itemsArray)

    var minDateNum: AnyObject! = itemsArray.valueForKeyPath("@max.self")
    var maxDateNum: AnyObject! = itemsArray.valueForKeyPath("@min.self")
    //println("\(maxDate, minDate)")

    var indexMax = itemsArray.indexOfObject(maxDateNum!)
    var indexMIn = itemsArray.indexOfObject(minDateNum!)

    //println("\(indexMax, indexMIn)")

    maxDate = modifieddateArray.objectAtIndex(indexMax)
    minDate = modifieddateArray.objectAtIndex(indexMIn)
    //println("\(maxDate, minDate)")
```

caluclating the time interval and finding the largest value as min date and smallest value as max date